# Как объединить две таблицы в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

Есть таблица T1:

```
id | A  | B
1  | a1 | 2
2  | a2 | 3
3  | a3 | 5
```

И таблица T2:

```
X
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Нужно получить результирующий набор следующего вида:(условия для join `T1.B=T2.X`)

```
A    | B    | X
NULL | NULL | 1
a1   | 2    | 2
a2   | 3    | 3
NULL | NULL | 4
a3   | 5    | 5
NULL | NULL | 6
```

Такое вообще возможно?

UPD:

Eсть одно лукавство:
таблицы T2 не существует физически - это мощный select, который производит некую последовательность в заданных пределах - в примере от 1 до 10.
То-есть нужный мне запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
select T1.id,T1.A,T1.B, T2.X from T1
join (мощный select, дающий на выходе один столбец X) as T2 on (T1.B=T2.X)
```

UPD2:

```
select DD.dte, acs.* FROM acs right join ((SELECT '2015-10-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY as dte FROM  (SELECT 0 a UNION SELECT 1 a UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 ) d, (SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40) m WHERE '2015-10-01' + INTERVAL a + b DAY  <  '2015-11-01' ORDER BY a + b) ) as DD on (acs.c_date=DD.dte)  WHERE c_date>='2015-10-01' AND c_date<='2015-10-31' and some_id=10 ORDER BY c_date ASC;
```

Таблица acs содержит записи для some_id=10 только с 2015-10-12 по 2015-10-20, а мне нужен полный месяц.

Comment: я так понял соединение по ключу B? Ну тогда к T2 делаете left join T1, либо к T1 right join T2

Comment: не работает. выдает только те записи, которые есть в T1

дополню свой вопрос пояснением

Comment: а кто сказал что надо join использовать? Я же написал - left join или right join, а у вас inner join, а он как раз и возвращает только те, что есть в обеих таблицах

Comment: @Борис И вы к этому добавили слово `right` и оно продолжает не работать ? Ваш мощный запрос справа, значит использовать надо right join

Comment: Парни - я пробовал и right и left -не получается!
Фиддл, который показал Mike - вселяет надежду, но ....

Сейчас будет уточнение №2.

Comment: `some_id=10` - этим вы все и портите, сделайте `(some_id=10 OR some_id IS NULL)` - и будет вам счастье

Comment: к сожалению - не помогло.

Comment: а, ну да - у вас же еще c_date есть - вообще удалите их, они вроде как не нужны (вы же уже отсеяли лишнее при джойне)

Comment: Супер! Да! Спасибо огромное! Именно это условие не давало нам построить счастливое будущее!

Comment: @Борис `union select 1 union select 2 ...` жуть то какая ... У меня во многих серьезных системах есть табличка seqnum вот в точности повторяющая по структуре вашу T2 из вопроса, и в ней "достаточное кол-во" записей. Запросы как то проще выглядят `select num from seqnum whetre num<=7` ну или `select num*10 ... num<=4` :)

Comment: @Mike: Мне самому не нравится. можно про seqnum подробностей узнать?

Comment: @Борис ну просто обычная таблица с 1 полем и в нем изначально занесены цифры подряд. обычно записей 100 бывает, что бы на все случаи жизни хватало. И в запросы ее просто клею когда числа по порядку нужны

Comment: Да?? Сспасибо. Попробую изменить запрос

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from T1
  right join T2 on T1.B=T2.X
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40fc/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table T1(id int, A char(2),B int);
insert into T1 values(1,"A1",1);
insert into T1 values(2,"A1",3);

create table T2(X int);
insert into T2 values(1);
insert into T2 values(2);
insert into T2 values(3);
insert into T2 values(4);
insert into T2 values(5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
  from T2
  left join T1 on T1.B=T2.X
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40fc/1/0)**:

```
| X |     id |      A |      B |
|---|--------|--------|--------|
| 1 |      1 |     A1 |      1 |
| 3 |      2 |     A1 |      3 |
| 2 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 4 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 5 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: не работает. выдает только те записи, которые есть в T1

Comment: Вы прямо вот так как ту сделали. никаких дополнительных условий у вас в запросе нет ? Потому как вот так работать просто обязано. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b40fc/1/0

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Могу привести реальный пример запроса - но он страшен :)

Comment: Просто у вас T1 первая в запросе, значит надо right а не left использовать. Перемена мест таблиц меняет результат !